# How to count attachments before save document in lotusscript?

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino, lotusscript, lotus

I would like to check whether attach an attachment in RichText field before save(it is a new document) the form in lotusscript. There are a RichText field naming "Attachs" and a button to run the below code. It shows "Please attach an attachment" when I click the button without attaching any attachment, and then it is still shows the same message when I have attached it. How can I solve this problem? Thanks a lot.

```
If uidoc.Document.Attachs(0) = "" Then    
    Msgbox "Please attach an attachment",,"Attention"       
Else
    Msgbox "Pass, you have attached an attachment"
End If
```

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately you cannot access attachments in a NotesRichtextItem with LotusScript before a document is saved.

BUT: Formula language "@AttachmentNames" can. You can leverage that:

```
Dim attachNames as Variant
attachNames = Evaluate( "@AttachmentName", uidoc.Document )
If attachNames(0) = "" then
  Msgbox "Please attach an attachment",,"Attention"       
Else
  Msgbox "Pass, you have attached an attachment"
End If
```

Comment: Great! It works. Thanks, Tode.